# How to deal with User Specified Local DateTime for Notification alert and Server Process?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, datetime

In my web project a user creates a todo list and he provides a datetime value for reminding him according to his local time. When this record is saved in the database, the server will process records periodically and notify the respective users.

The problem is that the user provided datetime can be different from the server datetime and testing the notify dateTime against server datetime would result in an incorrect notification.

So I need to know what is would be the best practice that application should send the notifications on a correct due date, which a user is expecting?

Comment: You should work with UTC dates

Comment: Can we store DateTime as UTC when a user is sending the future DateTime value from his computer calendar?

Comment: I think that NodaTime (http://nodatime.org/) is one of the best options available. There are lots of challenges there you can read this post http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Comment: Use some javascript to create a `Date` object from the user entered value and then the `.toUTCString()` function to convert it to UTC DateTime

Answer (score 1):

It is not mentioned in your question or comments yet, but part of the solution is to ensure that the user supplies or selects their current or operating time zone. When you evaluate their provided `DateTime` against the benchmark on the server, you can adjust the benchmark by taking the server time zone and client time zone into account. By calculating the benchmark when you evaluate against the provided DateTime, you can also avoid problems when daylight savings come into effect - knowing the time zone also takes care of that.

You can use UTC as suggested, but you still need to know the time zone of the user to translate correctly.

Comment: I think this a better solution and I was also of a similar view that I should pass client current time in Request Headers or in a Hidden Field and at the server side compute difference between server and client time and modify the user provided datetime.